# Call Stored procedure in Java , JSP using Liferay framework

Tags: java, jsp, stored-procedures, liferay, liferay-6

How should I call a stored procedure in java and in jsp file in Liferay?
I would like to see a sample example that will give me something to start with

Comment: what is `stored procedure in java`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to sources from Liferay :)

e.g.: 
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/document_library/edit_file_entry.jsp

~